# Is martinet a pejorative term?

Tags: word-meaning

The definition in the dictionary says "strict disciplinarian", and a disciplinarian is a person who practices discipline.

If you call someone a *martinet*, are you praising them or criticizing them?

Comment: It all depends on context.  "Welcome to guard school. You'd be wise to pick a seasoned guard as a role model and learn from him.  Joe, here, is one of our best martinets and we all aspire to reach his level."  OR "That martinet has no business in the classroom, I'm calling for his immediate resignation."

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martinet is interesting, though I'm not sure it answers your question.

Comment: Maybe your question belongs to EL&U. As you know, there are more native speakers of English on EL&U as compared to this site.

Answer (score 3):

In any context I've seen it in (up until Jim's comment at least), it has been invariably perjorative. It carries the connotations of being **unnecessarily** strict or inflexible, pompous and small-minded. The article linked by Tetsujin links usage of the term (in French) with the Devil and the English quote from Time magazine applies it to [Idi Amin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idi_Amin)!

Comment: I think the [etymology of martinet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Martinet) supports the idea that it's a negative term. Jean Martinet was extremely unpopular with his troops and supposedly killed by friendly fire.

Comment: @ColleenV [Surely not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy)

Comment: @CarSmack Not on etymology alone, but combined with the lack of examples of positive actual usage, I think it supports the idea that while being a disciplinarian isn't necessarily negative,  being a martinet is.

Answer (score 1):

When you call someone a disciplinarian, are you praising them or criticizing them?

As for *martinet,* several dictionaries give two definitions:

1. a strict disciplinarian, esp. a military one.
2. someone who stubbornly adheres to methods or rules.

I have not yet seen a dictionary mark the word as *pejorative.*

I would think Definition 2 lends itself to a negative connotation. But some people do not like *anything* that smacks of discipline,  and I imagine the such would also find *disciplinarian* to be pejorative.

Notice it is also possible to combine the two definitions, as in a military officer that stubbornly adheres to rules, procedures, or methods.

Some words lend themselves to negative or pejorative meaning but do not have to be:

martinet
disciplinarian
dictator
cafeteria lady

Comment: LOL at 'cafeteria lady'.